# Run a python code from terminal with arguments

Tags: python, terminal, arguments

With what python code can an argument be recognized as a string?[image: program ran]

for example:
"root:/user1/Folder1# python -W ignore run1.py Pustaka Sarawak
 Govt"
In the above example,  file 'run1.py' takes the argument "Pustaka Sarawak" recognizes it as a string and outputs "Govt" after performing a process.   What is the code to recognize "Pustaka Sarawak" as a string?  In the picture takes the Polis Diraja Malaysia and the output is 'Govt'

Answer (score 4):

You can use sys library to do that.

### Here is an example,

add-arg.py

```
import sys
num1 = sys.argv[1]
num2 = sys.argv[2]
print("The sum is ",int(num1)+int(num2))
```

terminal

```
~$ python add-arg.py 1 2
The sum is  3
```

Now you might see that I have used

```
num1 = sys.argv[1]
```

Instead of

```
num1 = sys.argv[0]
```

If you put sys.argv[0] then the program name "add-arg.py' will be the argument which will be assigned to num1.

### Here's an example illustrating the output due to sys.argv[0]

commandline-arg.py

```
import sys
name = sys.argv[0]
age = sys.argv[1]
print('Hi, ',name,' your age is ',age)
```

Terminal

```
~$ python commandline-arg.py sharon 22
Hi,  commandline-arg.py  your age is  sharon
```

Note: The arguments given will be taken as strings
Refer [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv) for more

Answer (score 1):

Look into python's sys.argv function.

```
import sys
x = str(sys.argv[1])
y = str(sys.argv[2])
```

x will be Pustaka, y will be Sarawak

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list, not a function.